# In Linux Mint how to mount a bootable Linux Mint USB drive?

Tags: linux

My main machine is running Linux Mint 18.1 Serena. I also have a bootable Linux Mint USB drive that I use when traveling with some of my personal files. Both of them are encrypted. The problem is that coping files between these two systems (main machine and USB drive) is painful as I’m unable to mount the USB drive in my main machine. This is what I have done so far:

1- Because both systems are encrypted, I followed the instructions in “How to mount encrypted LVM logical volume” (https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2015/11/16/how-to-mount-encrypted-lvm-logical-volume/).

2- That kind of worked, but both system’s volumes have the same VG name (vgdisplay). Both of them are named mint-vg. So, I renamed the USB volume using (https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/warning-duplicate-vg-name-server01-error/) as a guide. Now both volumes have different names (one mint-vg and the other mike-vg).

But now my USB drive does not boot, and that I have not been able to fix. Before I made things worse, I renamed my USB drive volume back to mint-vg, so it can boot.

I wondering if somebody have been able to successful mount a bootable Mint USB stick in a machine running Mint as well.